# React App loads audio file multiple times, causing a lot of bandwidth waste

Tags: reactjs, firebase, audio, timer, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple timer in React and I want to play a short mp3 file after it is finished.

```
import audio from './audio.mp3';
...

//Called exactly once when the timer is done
function triggerAudio()
{
    audio.play();
}
```

After deploying it to Firebase hosting, I noticed that it was using up a lot of bandwidth (1GB/hour!), and with it a huge bill, because as the timer runs it would continuously reload the audio file, well before the audio is actually played when the timer runs out. This is especially apparent in Microsoft Edge. Chrome seems better at caching it.

I tried to use external npm libraries, temporarily render `<audio src={happy}/>` in my render, and none of them solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try dynamically importing the audio? You could import the audio inside the triggerAudio() function

Comment: @AbhayAravinda would this import the audio one time every time it gets triggered?

Comment: I'm not really sure. It was just a suggestion